# Working Regular Expression not working in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have this working regular expression: `^(.*?)}`

It is used to find values between two braces, like :

```
[{test},{test2}]  // should only find [{test}
```

but in java this is not working:

```
            String regExpression = Pattern.quote("^(.*?)}");
            Pattern one = Pattern.compile(regExpression);
            Matcher matcherone = one.matcher("[{test},{test2}]");
            while (matcherone.find()) {
                Text = matcherone.group();
            }
```

Comment: You must escape the `}` - `\\}`

Comment: escape bracket as `\\}`

Comment: thank you for your quick response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the brace and remove `Pattern.quote`:

```
String regExpression = "^(.*?)\\}";
Pattern one = Pattern.compile(regExpression);
Matcher matcherone = one.matcher("[{test},{test2}]");
String Text = "";
if (matcherone.find()) {
  Text = matcherone.group();
}
System.out.println(Text);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/8KmV5O)

The `matcherone.group();` will match `[{test}`, and `group(1)` will return `[{test`.

Note that `Pattern.quote("^(.*?)}")` will add escaped before all the special regex metacharacters and will totally ruin the regex pattern.

And a note on the pattern: to match all substrings inside `{...}`, you can use

```
Pattern one = "\\{([^{}]*)\\}";
```

And get them using `.group(1)`.

Comment: You are welcome. I do not know why Java developers decided to make their regex engine that particular and why it can't disambiguate the `{` and `}` that make part of a limiting quantifier and which ones are  literal.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ever unsure about what needs to be escaped or not; if you need 2 backslashes or 4 in your string literal; etc, etc

You can use

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(literal))
```

For your example, it would be

```
    Pattern.compile("^(.*?)".concat(Pattern.quote("}")))
```

Answer (score 1):

As other already stated you have to escape the closing brace.
Braces must be escaped in regex since they are delimiters for [quantifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> Quantifiers specify how many instances of a character, group, or character class must be present in the input for a match to be found.

To test regex specific for Java you can use this online service : [Java regex tester](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com)